# The function groupby().sum() in a pandas dataframe is concatenate the hours not summing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, timedelta

I'm a beginner python dev and I probably missing something with my code.

I make a get in an API and get a JSON response, so I get the elements that I need and append in a list:

```py
def get_report(cookie):
    today = (datetime.today()-timedelta(days=0)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    link_report = f'https://atendimento.sistemainfo.com.br/Report/WorkTimeResultToJsonAsync?StartDate={today}&EndDate={today}&TicketType=&Agents%5B0%5D.Id=16086163&Agents%5B0%5D.ToDelete=False&Agents%5B1%5D.Id=40721217&Agents%5B1%5D.ToDelete=False&Agents%5B2%5D.Id=16810784&Agents%5B2%5D.ToDelete=False&Agents%5B3%5D.Id=19891551&Agents%5B3%5D.ToDelete=False&Agents%5B4%5D.Id=23034581&Agents%5B4%5D.ToDelete=False&Agents%5B5%5D.Id=21459575&Agents%5B5%5D.ToDelete=False&Agents%5B6%5D.Id=28407059&Agents%5B6%5D.ToDelete=False&Agents%5B7%5D.Id=34454555&Agents%5B7%5D.ToDelete=False&Agents%5B8%5D.Id=28492909&Agents%5B8%5D.ToDelete=False&_=1666122828849'
    request_report = requests.get(link_report, cookies=cookie)

    reports = json.loads(request_report.content)['list']

    print(reports)

    agent = []
    appointedTime = []

    for i in reports:
        agent.append(i['agent'])
        appointedTime.append(i['appointedTime'])

    df = pd.DataFrame(reports, columns=['agent', 'appointedTime'])
    df2 = df.groupby('agent').sum()
    print(df2)

get_report(get_cookies())
```

But my output is:

```
agent        |      appointedTime                                                   
Person 1      |    00:1000:0400:1500:0300:0200:5100:2100:0700:020

Person 2      |   00:3401:1600:0100:0201:0800:0200:1600:0200:17

Person 3       |                                              00:3300:17

Person 4       |    01:1300:0100:1900:2200:3000:1300:0900:1800:040...

Person 5        |        00:0400:0100:3600:1800:2100:1600:1201:0100:140...

Person 6        |     00:2100:0100:0100:0200:2300:0100:0100:0100:010...

Person 7        |                        01:0600:0100:0100:06

Person 8  | 00:3200:0200:0100:2200:0300:0200:0300:5700:040
```

Why the second column is concatenated and not a sum of the hours? I've tried some parses but didn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: could you please add an example of how `df` looks like? In principle, you'll have to convert the column [to timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) to be able to sum it, since you cannot "sum up" strings.

Comment: @FObersteiner Hi Fob, thanks for your answer. I solved the mistery create a tuple using the zip function, and after that, using a for loop and sum the hours.                                        for i in reports:
        agent.append(i['agent'])
        appointedtime.append(int(i['appointedTimeMinutes']))

    report_tuple = list(zip(agent, appointedtime))

    d = collections.defaultdict(int)
    a = []

    for agent, appointment in report_tuple:
        if agent not in a:
            a.append(agent)
        d[agent] += appointment / 60